# error while getting a response from stripe "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

Stripe Library referenced : Stripe.net 
Runtime Version:v4.0.30319
Version : 25.2.0.0

while getting a response from the stripe and calling the charge function() in am getting the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral" on the 
code mentioned below

```
<form action="/Pay/Charge" method="POST">
    <article>
        <label>Amount: $5.00</label>
    </article>
    <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
            class="stripe-button"
            data-key="@ViewBag.StripePublishKey"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-description="Sample Charge"
            data-amount="500">
    </script>
</form>
```

This view calls the below charge ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
        {
            var customers = new CustomerService();
            var charges = new ChargeService();

            var customer = customers.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken
            });

//Error on this line--↓

            var charge = charges.Create(new ChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Description = "Sample Charge",
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id
            });

            // further application specific code goes here

            return View();
        }
```

```
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

InnerException:Null
```

Comment: As its a nuget package, are you sure it got sent to the server?

Comment: The important part of the error message is  `The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`. It means you use a `'System.Collections.Immutable` dll that's different from the one the library expected. If you search for the error message you'll find a lot of duplicates. The solution is to add a binding redirect in your web.config that points to the dll version you've added to your project. If you add that assembly through NuGet the binding redirect elements are added automatically

Comment: this is a demo project which i am try at my local machine @BugFinder

Comment: The latest stable version of [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) is 1.5. Add that version and make sure web.config contains an entry that redirects to this

Comment: I'm facing the same thing with Stripe.NET 26.1.0. While now the latest version of `System.Collections.Immutable` is 1.7.0. I assume it is backward compatible with 1.2.3.0, I don't understand why Stripe.NET is tripping up on this transitive dependency...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take when I tried to fix this problem:

1. I needed to add `System.Collections.Immutable` to my `web.config` file (or if you happen to work on a desktop app it's the app config). Before this error there wasn't an entry for that assembly in the web.config.
2. The `NuGet` **package version is not the same as the assembly version** for whatever reason. This hindered me for several hours, because I knew I had to add a version redirection to my `web.config`.

Currently the `NuGet` package version is 1.7, while the assembly version is `1.2.5.0`. Finally I found that out with `PowerShell`:

```
PS> [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\WebAppSourceCodePath\bin\System.Collections.Immutable.dll').Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      2      5      0
```

Knowing that I added this entry:

```
<configuration>
...
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="1.2.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
...
</configuration>
```

Also, you need the proper `publicKeyToken` and full specification in the entry above. That can be read out using PowerShell as well.

```
PS> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\WebAppSourceCodePath\bin\System.Collections.Immutable.dll').FullName
System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Answer (score 0):

In case System.Collections.Immutable is already installed, Check out the version of it in packages.config in case it is a different version it won't work, modify it manually to be the same version as it is logged in the exception and rebuild your solution to install the needed version.

```
<package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**Update:**

Original question was about version 25.2.0 of `Stripe.net` and in that old version there was dependency on `System.Collections.Immutable`, howeever latest version for  has no dependency on  anymore: [image]

Check out the link [Stripe.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net)

Comment: Why 1.5 or 1.7 would not be backward compatible with the 1.2.3.0? I really don't want to downgrade that package just because something is wacked up inside Stripe.NET

Comment: @CsabaToth Latest version has no dependency for `System.Collections.Immutable` anymore, I will update my answer please check it